# Cant stop while loop with button in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Kind of new to threading.

My current code;

```
public boolean running = false;
private void jStartButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
     running = true;
     (new Thread(new Home())).start();

}    
private void jStopButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   running = false;
   System.out.println("trying to stop");
}  


public void run() {
   while(running){
       //continously run code from a file thats updated every few seconds, running=false when its found what its looking for
   }

}
```

jStopButton2 is being processed and running is set to false in debug, but its never recognized by the run() thread.
run() has its own running=false built it when its found what its looking for (and it stops the while loop), but right now there is no way for me to manually stop it if I want to stop.

I know I have my thread wrong, any help? Could it be that everything inside the thread is locked? So it doesn't recognize running bolean being changed? How would I go about changing that? o.o

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `Home` class in this point

```
(new Thread(new Home())).start();
```

So your flag `running`  will be initialized again ( if it's not static)
So try using the same instance of House, and you'll keep the value of `running`

I mean

```
(new Thread(this)).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple synchronization application (based on your code that uses a `running` flag) that launches the second thread (your `Home` class) from the main thread, waits a bit and then decides to stop the second thread. It gives time to the second thread to finish its work and/or observe the `running` flag has been changed and, finally, finishes the main thread as well.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Home home = new Home();
        Thread thread = home.jStartButton1ActionPerformed(null);

        System.out.println("main thread sleeping");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        System.out.println("main thread deciding to stop secondary thread...");
        home.jStopButton2ActionPerformed(null);

        System.out.println("main thread waiting for secondary thread to finish...");
        thread.join();

        System.out.println("main thread finished");
    }
}

class Home implements Runnable
{
    public boolean running = false;

    public Thread jStartButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        running = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        System.out.println("secondary thread started");

        // Returning thread instance so that the main thread can synchronize with it (wait for it to finish)
        return thread;
    }

    public void jStopButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        running = false;
        System.out.println("trying to stop");
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running){
            //continously run code from a file thats updated every few seconds, running=false when its found what its looking for
            // Simulating work by sleeping.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            System.out.println("secondary thread running...");
        }
        System.out.println("secondary thread stopped");
    }
}
```

The problem in your example is that you were doing `new Home()` every time, and thus creating a new runnable instance (with its own `running` version) that you could not control. In the example above, the current runnable instance is the one launching the thread, so it is making sure to set itself as the code to be executed by the thread, thus retaining control of the `running` field. The main thread controls the `Home` instance so it also controls the `running` field when calling the `stop` method on the `Home` instance.